# Be confused with msg_name field in msghdr structure

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming, embedded-linux

In user space, I encapsulated a L3 packet using `sock_raw` (including IP header) and send to kernel space using `sock_sendmsg()` using `msghdr` structure

```
struct msghdr {
    void         *msg_name;       /* optional address */
    struct iovec *msg_iov;        /* scatter/gather array */
    ...
};
```

I cannot understand clearly the roles of `msg_name`. I already specified the source IP and dest IP in L3 header. Why do I need `msg_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `msg_name` and `msg_namelen` fields of `struct msghdr` have the same function as the `dest_addr` and `addrlen` arguments to [`sendto`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto): they specify the destination address.  They are intended to be used with *normal* unconnected datagram sockets. For instance, when sending UDP packets with `sendmsg` on an `AF_INET`/`SOCK_DGRAM` socket, you supply only the payload, not the headers, in the iovec, and the destination address goes in `msg_name` + `msg_namelen`.

[`raw(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/raw), the manpage describing `SOCK_RAW` sockets, indicates that you *are* allowed to put the header into the `iovec` when using raw sockets (note in particular the discussion of `IP_HDRINCL`) but does not make clear what you should set `msg_name` and `msg_namelen` to in that case.  I would recommend you try setting both of them to 0 and see if that works.